# How to open wifi settings for iOS in React native

Tags: ios, react-native, linker, settings

In my React Native application, I want to open the wifi settings from my app.

I used **Linking.openURL("App-Prefs:root=WIFI");**. It's redirecting to main settings page only. That's also fine.

But most of the developers said, their app got rejected by apple store due to using private APIs like "App-Prefs:root=WIFI".

What's the perfect solution for this? Please advice. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: it not work anymore > ios 10. Anyway apple not allowed it, if you use App-Prefs your app will rejected https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/75110

Comment: Thanks @anthonywillismuñoz Is there any other solution to open atleast main settings page in iOS?